# Contact Staff Stack Exchange or with form or an email

Tags: support, stackexchange, request-for-information

I would to to know what is how I can  to contact Stack Exchange Staff to send a private message via email or through a private form. Thank you.

Is it this: https://stackoverflow.com/contact?referrer=https://stackoverflow.co? Or this? https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact

Answer (score 1):

The link for the staff is: https://tex.stackexchange.com/contact.